# How can I implement this solution?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, algorithm, spring-data-mongodb

I need to solve some exercises for my college, this is the picture of the problem.

I just finish the structure of the project, I'm using MongoDB, Spring Data and Spring Boot, but i have no idea how I'm gonna do it. I was thinking use dijkstra algorithm.

Comment: As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) says it: *"Dijkstra's algorithm is an algorithm for finding the **shortest** paths between nodes in a graph"*. You task is to *"compute **all** available routes"*, so a simple brute-force search what you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to read about Depth First Search (DFS) implemented in graphs:

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-first-search-or-dfs-for-a-graph/
- https://medium.com/basecs/deep-dive-through-a-graph-dfs-traversal-8177df5d0f13

Also check Breadth First Search (BFS):

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-search-or-bfs-for-a-graph/